# recovering original value after predicting with by converting np.logv alues

Tags: python

I use a dataset to predict the value of  player, during data preparation and cleaning before  building  my model I converted some variables to Nlog (np.log) which including the dependent variable which is 'y'.  I build my model and a little demo app with it . the app and model is  predicting  and giving nlog values  as the value of the player
Please I need help on how to convert the variables back original values and for my final prediction and app to be able to display like the original values  of the player in the original data sets  not the nlog values i used for prediction.

i do not really know what to do

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of np.log is np.exp. So, if

`y = np.log(x)`

Then `x = np.exp(y)` will get x back from the log values.

Please include a minimum reproducible example if you need more help.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html